# Subset of 2 arrays

Tags: dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Given 2 arrays (A and B) of size N and a number X. We have to select a subset of numbers from both the arrays such that -

1. Size of union of indices selected in both subset = N . Same index can be selected in both arrays.
2. Sum of elements in both the subsets must be at least X.

Find the number of different ways to select subsets from A and B.

What I thought -> Compute and store the size of subsets from both arrays whose sum >=X (we can now keep adding more elements in these and the sum will be greater than X) and then multiply the sizes {n,0},{n-1,1}etc but I think this will take a lot of time and the code will be a mess as well. Anybody can think of any beautiful way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think I fully understand the problem. If the same index can be selected in both arrays and the size of both subsets must be `n`, does this imply we can leave elements out entirely? Can you show a few examples or link to an online judge/problem description (if applicable)? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about how the two arrays A and B is different from an array of say size of 2N and you have to choose N indexes from the 2N array?